# Fourier Series, finding coefficients

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I am working on this problem:

*Let $f$ be a periodic function  of period $12$ defined by*

$$f(x)=$$\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }-6<x\leq0\\
x & \text{ if }0<x\leq 6
\end{cases}

*Then the Fourier series of $f$ is*

$a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}{6}+b_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{6}$

*find $a_0 , a_n , b_n$*

I've solved for $a_0$ and $a_n$ already, but I'm having trouble getting a good answer for my $b_n$

I'm taking the integrals $$\int_{-6}^{0} {\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{6})}  dx + \int_{0}^{6} {x\sin(\frac{n \pi x}{6})}dx $$

For the first integral, I'm getting $$(\frac{-1}{n\pi} - (-1)^n)$$ with $(-1)^n$ being an alternative form of $\cos(n\pi)$

And for the second integral, I'm getting $$\frac{-36}{n\pi} (-1)^n$$

which put together, my final answer should be: $$\frac{-1}{n\pi} - (-1)^n + \frac{-36}{n\pi} (-1)^n$$

But that's incorrect. Any idea where I'm going wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have lost a few factors of $\frac{1}{6}$ and a term in your $b_n$. Since I don't know what you obtained for $a_n$, here is a worked derivation.

The Fourier series is given by $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(n\pi x/6) + b_n\sin(n\pi x/6)$$
where
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{6}\int_{-6}^0dx + \frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^6 xdx = 1 + \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{2} \times 6^2 = 4$$
and for $n > 0$
\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac{1}{6}\int_{-6}^0 \cos(n\pi x/6)dx + \frac{1}{6}\int_0^6 x\cos(n\pi x/6)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{n\pi}\left[\sin(n\pi x/6)\right]_{-6}^0 + \frac{1}{n\pi}\left[x\sin(n\pi x/6)\right]_0^6 - \frac{1}{n\pi}\int_0^6 \sin(n\pi x/6)dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}[-\cos(n\pi x/6)]_0^6 \\
&= \frac{6}{n^2\pi^2}((-1)^n-1)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
b_n &= \frac{1}{6}\int_{-6}^0 \sin(n\pi x/6)dx + \frac{1}{6}\int_0^6 x\sin(n\pi x/6)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{n\pi}\left[-\cos(n\pi x/6)\right]_{-6}^0 + \frac{1}{n\pi}\left[-x\cos(n\pi x/6)\right]_0^6 + \frac{1}{n\pi}\int_0^6 \cos(n\pi x/6)dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{n\pi}(-1-(-1)^n) -\frac{1}{n\pi}(6(-1)^n-1) \\
&= \frac{1}{n\pi}(-5(-1)^n)
\end{align*}

Hence the Fourier series for $f(x)$ is

$$f(x) = 2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[ \frac{6((-1)^n-1)}{n^2\pi^2}\cos(n\pi x/6) -\frac{5(-1)^n}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi x/6)\right]$$

Comment: That is still incorrect unfortunately

Comment: Then I will update my answer with the full calculation of the series.